# Intellij syntax highlighting of javascript and php in the same file

Tags: php, javascript, intellij-idea

I have a JavaScript file that needs to have some PHP tags in it. Something like this:

```
var chart = {
  init: function() {
    ...
    drawChart(this.data);
    ...
  },

  data: <?php echo $this->data ?>
}
```

The output is obviously a pure JavaScript file and functionally this is working fine. However, IntelliJ isn't correctly highlighting the code. If I name the file with a .js extension, it starts showing errors as soon as it runs across a PHP tag. If I name the file with a .php extension, it doesn't show any syntax errors, but doesn't highlight any of the JavaScript, only the PHP.

I know it's capable of doing this because I can name the file with a .php extension and surround all the code with `<script>` tags and everything highlights correctly. Unfortunately that would break my application.

Does anyone know of a way I can get highlighting to work for both languages without `script` tags?

Comment: That's because a .js file is not traditionally parsed by PHP on a webserver. It's assumed to be pure javascript. As well, there's really no such thing as a "php script" - there's just files that happen to have one or more PHP code blocks embedded within. ANY file can be a php file,  as long as the `<?php` and `?>` blocks are not used for other purposes.

Comment: Not sure about IntelliJ IDEA but most editors will assume that non-PHP code in a PHP script is HTML. While it's often a safe assumption, it'd be great the it was not a hard-coded option.

Comment: Do you have intelliLang enabled. Did you try the "Inject Language" intention?

Comment: I've looked into the "Inject Language" intention, but everything I've seen seems to indicate it only works for string literals. I want to output what will look like a hard coded javascript array from php, not a javascript string.

Comment: this: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Syntax+highlighting+of+PHP+inside+JavaScript+%28and+other+languages%29